# h:selectManyMenu - how to prevent someone from changing value but not disabled

Tags: primefaces

I want to show a h:selectManyMenu with some selected Values. The user should be able to scroll and see the values, but should not be able to change anything. But if I set disabled to true, then the menu is disabled and is not scrollable. Are there any ways of doing it? I am using primefaces 3.5

Answer (score 1):

As the name of the component says it's a "select" many menu, which is intended to be used to select values. It would be illogical to disable this functionality.

You should try to take a look at different components like the DataList:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dataListHome.jsf

Perhaps combined with a ScrollPanel:

http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/scrollPanel.jsf